# How can I view a events sent to a topic?

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I created an Azure Event Grid Topic and I can send events to it. How can I view the events submitted to that topic?

In the Azure Portal, I can view the Event Grid Topic and see the topic's metrics but I cannot find a way to view the event messages.

At the moment, I created a workaround where I send all messages to a storage queue. The issue with this, Azure Storage Explorer doesn't let me scroll through thousands of messages; it limits me to viewing a single page of 50 +/- records.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the [Azure Event Grid Tester](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1254463/Azure-Event-Grid-Tester). You can clone any event subscription to the local machine subscriber via Hybrid Connection and/or ngrok tunnel channel.

The following screen snippet shows this tester with **2079** events on the custom topic *rk20180724topic2*:

[image]